# Hide author bio

Tags: html, css

I have to convert a PSD to (x)HTML for a client of mine witch in turn will use that theme for a client of him.

Now the question is, is there a way to protect my copyrights from within the page for copyrights like ?

In example, is there a way to leave somethink like that into the code and protected from removal;

```
<meta name="author" content="My name" />
```

Another and last question is, if I upload that project in my portfolio, will be that wrong from my side ? When I mean in my portfolio, I don't mean to represent that project as a full project developed by me, but as a PSD to (x)HTML Convertion project.

Comment: Copyright laws differ from country to country. Best to ask a lawyer.

Comment: ... and I have no idea if there's a place on earth where the simple process of format conversion in itself can be copyrighted at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is really important to you, I'd recommend that you make it part of the contract between you and your designers. They provide you a PSD, you provide them XHTML on the condition that they don't remove your attribution links from the code.

Programmatic methods would be unreliable, so it's probably best to settle it with a gentleman's agreement.

Answer (score 5):

> is there a way to leave something like that into the code and protected from removal;

No. HTML is a completely open format; you can not protect it from being copied; you can also not prevent anybody with access to the HTML from removing the notice.

If this is about making sure you are identified as the author of the work, consider making a (written) agreement with your client saying that there will be an author notice in the HTML, and they are not allowed to remove it.

Comment: Re your second question - that's not really programming related and probably depends a lot on your situation, the law in your country and/or any agreement you have with your client. But as long as you make it clear that it's not your design, and you just did the HTML conversion, I guess there's nothing speaking *fundamentally* against mentioning the job in your portfolio

Comment: You can put watermarks on the images. But in general you're right.

Comment: I don't like to add watermark. Just I like to know if there is a way to represent that as a work of mine, without affect the work of my client in somehow.

Comment: +1 for settling it via contract. Didn't see that part until after I posted my response :P

Answer (score 2):

@Merianous; there is a new term called `humans.txt` which use by [google](http://www.google.com/humans.txt) also.

this also use by boilerplate in there project http://html5boilerplate.com/humans.txt

check this link http://humanstxt.org/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: NO

The long answer: you can use many tricks to protect you bio in code, but this will only made harder to remove: it will be always possibile to steal your work with the necessary efforts.

Comment: Do you have any trick example to show me ?

Comment: Would be necessary to see the generated code

Answer (score 1):

You normally don't see those kinds of things directly in the HTML. You're more than welcome to add comments to the CSS:

```
/*
 * Author : Adam Wexler
 * Email : adam@wexcode.com
 * All code (c) 2011 Wexcode
 * All rights reserved
 */
```

Comment: That is good looking. My only problem is that I want to leave my info in safe place. :(